# Can cube be a Cross-polytope?

Tags: geometry

I was reading about [L1-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) where I came across the term [Cross-Polytype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_polytope). In the link for Cross-Polytope, examples are given for Cross-Polytope in different dimensions. What I understood from the examples is that the sides should be formed from equal length line segments. In that case, can a cube be called a Cross-Polytope in 3 dimensions? and in that case can any shape with equal length sides be called a Cross-Polytope? for instance, a square pyramid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can a cube be called a Cross-Polytope in 3 dimensions?

It's made clear in [the Wikipedia article you link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) that **the** cross-polytope in $3$ dimensions is not the cube:

> In 3 dimensions it is an octahedron

Also from the article, the definition makes clear that there is only *one* cross-polytope in $n$ dimensions, the object whose

> vertices … are all the permutations of $(±1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$

Since that doesn't describe a cube, the answer to the question in your title is simply **no**, and similarly to your other questions: there is only *one* $n$-cross-polytope for any given $n$.